# How to use join using lambda expression in Asp MVC Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join, lambda

I saw many articles on join in lambda expression format but i got an error in join.

I have two table one is `tbl_payment` and another is `tbl_bill`.
`tbl_bank` has `ID`(Primary Key), `BILL_TYPE`.
`tbl_payment` has `ID`(Primary Key),`AMT`,`BILL_ID`(Foreign Key of `tbl_bank`).

I want to get all data form `tbl_payment` and bill_type from `tbl_bill` in one query result.

Code :

```
ViewBag.requestHistory =
               db.tbl_bill.Join(db.tbl_payment, x => x.ID, y => y.BILL_ID,
    (x, y) => new {x.BILL_TYPE,y.ID,y.AMT,y.COMMENT,y.PAYMENT_METHOD,y.STATUS}).ToList();
```

It's gave an error :

```
The type arguments for method `Querable.Join<TOuter,.....> cannot be infrred from the usage`.
```

Comment: mark any post as your accepted answer so that other people would prefer that answer

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the verbose linq syntax for joins

```
var requestHistory = 
    from bill in db.tbl_bill
    join payment in db.tbl_payment on bill.ID equals payment.BILL_ID
    select new {bill.BILL_TYPE, payment.ID, etc}
```

Comment: It still giving an error `type inference failed in the call to 'join'` .

Comment: @ManishTiwari  that might be because one of your foreign keys is nullable  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345039/type-inference-failed-in-a-call-to-join-on-nullable-and-non-nullable-int

Comment: i did this but nothing new happen .

Comment: @ManishTiwari for the record, what I posted is just to demonstrate syntax.  if `bill.ID` doesn't correspond to `payment.BILL_ID`, then you might want to join on something else